# Idiom similar to "saved by the bell"

Tags: idiom-requests

I am writing a story in which a posh, pretentious grandmother is rather angry at her grandson for being sarcastic. Just as she is about to scold him, his uncle steps in and directs the conversation elsewhere. I would like a way to describe the uncle's actions in a tongue-in-cheek way. (The story is set in the 1940s.)

Is there an idiom I can use here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can I take it that Uncle does not literally "step in" but has been listening and deliberately diverts the conversation? IOW it was no accident.

Comment: [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=saved+by+the+bell+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=saved+by+the+bell+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j0i22i30l3.1539452744j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives two senses for '[be] saved by the bell: '
escape from a difficult situation narrowly or by an unexpected intervention.' 'or' should of course be 'and/or'. But do you require the 'last minute' or 'unexpected intervention' sense, or either or both?

Answer (score 1):

*In the nick of time* is one related expression. However, an idiom by itself my not be wry enough for you, unless you tie it in with something the uncle says—perhaps with some kind of play on words. For example, if the uncle were named Nicholas.

**In the nick of time** (idiom)

> *Informal*
>
> Just before the last moment when something can be changed or something
> bad will happen
>
> *He decided to go just in the nick of time.*
>
> *The ambulance arrived in the nick of time.* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20nick%20of%20time)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the idiom ***within a whisker of***:

> Very close to something.
>
> - I swear the car came ***within a whisker of** hitting* the train, but stopped at the last second. ([Freedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/within+a+whisker+of), quoting Farlex)

I think you would get the right *tongue-in-cheek* tone as you call it if you combined with another funny idiom which would describe the situation:

> I came ***within a whisker of*** ***getting the rough edge of my grandmother's tongue***, but just then my uncle stepped in and...

The second idiom is *to give someone the (rough) edge of your tongue*:

> If you *give someone the rough side of your tongue* or *the rough edge of your tongue*, ***you speak angrily to them about something that they have done wrong.***
>
> - He's really going to give the boy the rough side of his tongue.
>
> Note: You can also say that ***someone gets the rough side or edge of your tongue*** or ***feels the rough side or edge of your tongue***.
>
> - As Archer watched the others walk away, he knew he was going to ***get the rough edge of his father's tongue***.
> - They ***felt the rough edge of their captain's tongue*** when things went wrong. ([FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+rough+side+of+tongue))

Answer (score 0):

The uncle **spared his blushes**, preventing him from being embarrassed.

Examples from [The idioms](https://www.theidioms.com/spare-someones-blushes/) :

- My teacher spoke up to spare the blushes of the new student.
- LeBron
  James dunked as time ran out to win the game and spare the blushes of
  the Los Angeles Lakers.
- John’s big brother saved his blushes by
  catching him when he fell out of the tree.
- Stacy decided not to sing
  so she could spare the blushes of her sister.
- Eric tried to spare his
  blushes after falling over the skateboard in the hallway.
- Cristiano
  Ronaldo saved the team’s blushes by scoring the only century in the
  test series.
- I’ll spare my blushes by not going into detail but the
  food wasn’t good.
- A lack of rehearsal time gave me ample excuses to
  spare my blushes.

In a less informal way, one may say that the uncle [**saved the day**](https://www.oysterenglish.com/idiom-save-the-day.html) of his nephew.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the metaphor **pull someone's chestnuts out of the fire**.

> *(to) pull (one’s) chestnuts out of the fire*
>
> Meaning:
>
> Depending on the context this can mean
>
> 1. to save one from some difficult or precarious situation

[[tocatdelbolet](https://tocatdelbolet.cat/en/to-pull-ones-chestnuts-out-of-the-fire/)]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull_someone%27s_chestnuts_out_of_the_fire) adds a 'last minute' allusion:

> *pull someone’s chestnuts out of the fire*: Synonym of *pull someone's  bacon out of the fire*
>
> 1. rescue someone, especially at the last moment

- *But Uncle Bob pulled his chestnuts out of the fire, quickly changing the subject.*

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the uncle **came to his/the rescue.** [TFD defines this as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+rescue)

> To help someone in trouble. The phrase can be used for both serious and trivial situations.

Answer (score -1):

One descriptive idiom is to say that the uncle acts as “deus ex machina”. This Latinism is a literary device that has been used in storytelling since ancient Greek times.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina)
> a plot device whereby a seemingly unsolvable problem in a story is suddenly or abruptly resolved by an unexpected and unlikely occurrence.

In this case, it is tongue-in-cheek to describe such a trivial circumstance in such a higher register Latinism.